# Results of asyncio are not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am learning `asyncio` library to do some tasks I want to achieve. I wrote the following code to teach myself on how to be able to switch to so another task while the original one is being executed. As you can see below, the `summation()` should be performed until a condition is met where it should jump to the `secondaryTask()`. After `secondaryTask()` is finished, it should return back to `summation()` where hopefully it gets finished. The potential results should be `sum=1225` and `mul=24`.

```
import asyncio, time


async def summation():
    print('Running summation from 0 to 50:')
    sum = 0
    for i in range(25):
        sum = sum + i
        if i != 25:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0) # pretend to be non-blocking work (Jump to the next task)
    print('This message is shown because summation() is completed! sum= %d' % sum)


async def secondaryTask():
    print('Do some secondaryTask here while summation() is on progress')
    mul = 1
    for i in range(1, 5):
        mul = mul * i
        time.sleep(0.1)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print('This message is shown because secondaryTask() is completed! Mul= %d' % mul)

t0 = time.time()
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(summation()), ioloop.create_task(secondaryTask())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
ioloop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
ioloop.close()
t1 = time.time()
print('Total time= %.3f' % (t1-t0))
```

This code does not perform as expected because `sum=300` as oppose to be `sum=1225`. Clearly that `summation()` does not continue while `secondaryTask()` is being processed. How can I modify `summation()` to be able to do the summation of the remaining 25 values on the background?

Thank you

Comment: Python range is end-exclusive, so `i != 25` will always evaluate to true; you probably meant to write `i != 24`, or simply put the final `await` after the loop. Even with that fixed, it is not clear what you thought the final `asyncio.sleep(0)` would accomplish. Since `summation` has 25 iterations taking 0.1s each and `secondaryTask` has only 4 iterations taking 0.1s each, `secondaryTask` will have finished by the time `summation()` ends. Also, why did you expect the other task to influence the sum printed by `summation`, since they have no shared state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just your careless. You want to run `summation` from 0 to 50, your `summation` function should be `for i in range(50)`

Comment: Oh I am so sorry! I didn't notice that. I was a bit tired that I couldn't see this little mistake.